# How To Slide Up others When another is SlideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with number of rows that some of rows are hidden and only visible when "show" button clicked. My question is how can slide up other Rows when a row is slide down?
Here is my snippet :-

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW</a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW</a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all `$(".content")` element then exclude the current `content` element using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), to use [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) on them.

```
$(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the content element
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");

    //slide up others 
    $(".content").not(content).slideUp();

    //toggle current
    content.slideToggle();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");
    $(".content").not(content).slideUp();
    content.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW</a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW</a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture your selected content in a variable, call `slideToggle()` on it, and then call `slideUp()` on every *other* `.content` element.

For more information, you can take a look at [the jQuery docs category for sliding](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selected = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content")
    selected.slideToggle();
    $('.content').not(selected).slideUp()
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW</a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW</a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```